# Why a map in $W_{{loc}}^{1,\frac{n}{2}}$ whose differential is in $L_{loc}^{n}$ belongs to $W_{{loc}}^{1,n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, integral-inequality

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ an open subset.
Let $f \in W_{{loc}}^{1,\frac{n}{2}}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n)$, and suppose also that $df \in L_{loc}^{n}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^{n^2})$.

> How can I prove that $f \in W_{{loc}}^{1,n}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Clearly $|df|^n$ is locally integrable. We need to prove $|f|^n$ is locally integrable.

My first thought was to use Sobolev inequality:

Let $p<n$. For every $f \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n)$
$$ \|f\|_{p^*} \le C \| df\|_p \tag{1}$$ where $p^*$ is the Sobolev conjugate of $p$, i.e. $1/p=1/p^*+1/n$. Taking $p=n/2$ we get $p^*=n$, so inequality $(1)$ becomes

$$ \|f\|_{n} \le C \| df\|_{n/2}. \tag{2}$$

The problem is that Sobolev inequality only holds for maps in $W^{1,p}_0$, not in $W^{1,p}$ in general. (Unless $\Omega$ satisfies some very specific properties, which I do not want to assume).

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: But you want only $loc$  right? You may just assume that $f$ is defined on a ball $B \subset \Omega$.

Comment: Yes, I only want *loc*. How does this help? You mean to take the convolution of $f$ with some mollifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The goal is to prove that $|f|^n$ is *locally* integrable. This is equivalent to being integrable on every ball $B$ contained in $\Omega$. The Sobolev embedding theorem applies on $B$, as it "satisfies some very specific properties" which we do not need to assume of $\Omega$ itself.

Comment: I know some time has passed, but perhaps you have a reference for the fact Sobolev embedding holds on a ball domain for $W^{1,p}$, and not just for $W^{1,p}_0$? Adams's book describes something called the *cone condition*, but I am not sure this condition applies to a ball. (It's phrasing also looks a bit complicated to me. I wonder if there is a simple adaptation of the standard proof of the $W^{1,p}_0$ case to balls).

Comment: The cone condition certainly holds for a ball, and for any bounded domain with smooth boundary ($C^2$ is enough).  For a ball centered at $0$: for each $x\in \partial B$ the cone with vertex $x$ and base equal to $B\cap x^\perp$ (a cross-section of $B$ orthogonal to $x$ is contained in $B$, and all these cones are congruent. (This argument generalizes to any convex domain, even without boundary smoothness.)